# Find a closed form for the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}\sqrt{y(1-y)}\sqrt{1-xy}}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I found this double integral in [this group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/170225716325580/permalink/6716476201700466/?mibextid=Nif5oz)

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}\sqrt{y(1-y)}\sqrt{1-xy}}dxdy$$

After integrating with respects to $x$ (or $y$, the order is not important because of the symmetry), I get this integral

$$\displaystyle2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K(y)}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}dy$$

Where $K(y)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

WolframAlpha says its closed form is $$\frac{256\pi^3}{\Gamma^4{\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)}}$$ or it is equavalent $$\frac{\pi^3}{\Gamma^4{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}}$$

I also try to use series expansion of $K(y)$ but the sum is more complicated. Any another approach is welcome, and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the value of the following double integral:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{x\left(1-x\right)}\sqrt{y\left(1-y\right)}\sqrt{1-xy}}\approx13.7504.$$

---

Consider the evaluation of the following integral for $z<1$:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-zt\right)\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-zt\right)\left(1-t\right)\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\left(1+u\right)\left[1-z\left(\frac{u}{1+u}\right)\right]\sqrt{u}};~~~\small{\left[t=\frac{u}{1+u}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\left(1+u-zu\right)\sqrt{u}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\left(1+v\right)\sqrt{v}};~~~\small{\left[u=\frac{v}{1-z}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{2}{1+w^{2}};~~~\small{\left[v=w^{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-z}},\\
\end{align}$$

$$\implies\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\left(1-zt\right)\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}};~~~\small{z<1}.$$

We can use this integral representation to rewrite $\mathcal{I}$ as a triple integral that is symmetric in its three variables.

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}\sqrt{u\left(1-u\right)}\sqrt{1-tu}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}\sqrt{u\left(1-u\right)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\left(1-tuv\right)\sqrt{v\left(1-v\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\left(1-tuv\right)\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)}\sqrt{u\left(1-u\right)}\sqrt{v\left(1-v\right)}}\\
&=\frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\left(1-x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}\right)^{-1}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\sqrt{1-z^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[(t,u,v)=(x^{2},y^{2},z^{2})\right]}\\
&=\frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1-\sin^{2}{\xi}\sin^{2}{\eta}\sin^{2}{\omega}};~~~\small{\left[(x,y,z)=(\sin{\xi},\sin{\eta},\sin{\omega})\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1-\sin^{2}{\xi}\sin^{2}{\eta}\sin^{2}{\omega}};~~~\small{even\,symmetry}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1-\sin{\xi}\sin{\eta}\sin{\omega}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1+\sin{\xi}\sin{\eta}\sin{\omega}};~~~\small{P.F.D.}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1-\sin{\xi}\sin{\eta}\sin{\omega}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1-\sin{\xi}\sin{\eta}\sin{\omega}};~~~\small{\left[\omega\mapsto-\omega\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1-\sin{\xi}\sin{\eta}\sin{\omega}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\xi\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\eta\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{1}{1-\cos{\xi}\cos{\eta}\cos{\omega}};~~~\small{\left[(\xi,\eta,\omega)\mapsto(\frac{\pi}{2}-\xi,\frac{\pi}{2}-\eta,\frac{\pi}{2}-\omega)\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{8}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+y^{2}\right)\left(1+z^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1-y^{2}}{1+y^{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1-z^{2}}{1+z^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[(\xi,\eta,\omega)\mapsto\left(2\arctan{(x)},2\arctan{(y)},2\arctan{(z)}\right)\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{8}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+y^{2}\right)\left(1+z^{2}\right)-\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-z^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}}\\
\end{align}$$

Switching to spherical coordinates with

$$\begin{align}
&x=r\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}\\
&y=r\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}\\
&z=r\cos{\left(\theta\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

we find the triple integral is now separable:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}r\,\frac{r^{2}\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{r^{2}+r^{6}\sin^{4}{\left(\theta\right)}\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}r\,\frac{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}}{1+r^{4}\sin^{4}{\left(\theta\right)}\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\cos^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}};~~~\small{\left[r=\frac{x}{\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\right]}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac12\sin{\left(2\varphi\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}};~~~\small{\left[\varphi\mapsto\frac12\varphi\right]}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}};~~~\small{symmetry}\\
&=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Observing that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{4\left(1+y\right)y^{3/4}};~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt[4]{y}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{4\left(1-t\right)\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{3/4}};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{t}{1-t}\right]}\\
&=\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t^{3/4}\left(1-t\right)^{1/4}}\\
&=\frac14\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac34\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac34\right)}}{4\,\Gamma{\left(1\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\pi\csc{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}}{4}\\
&=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}\\
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}};~~~\small{\left[\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[\varphi=\arcsin{\left(x\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}\sqrt[4]{y}\sqrt{1-y}};~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt{y}\right]}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,y^{-3/4}(1-y)^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac12\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}}{2\,\Gamma{\left(\frac34\right)}},\\
\end{align}$$

we obtain our final result

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{\left(\theta\right)}}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{1+x^{4}}\\
&=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}\left[\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\right]^{2}\\
&=2\left[\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}}{2\,\Gamma{\left(\frac34\right)}}\right]^{2}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}^{2}}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\right]^{2}\\
&=\frac{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}\right]^{4}}{4\pi}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: The skill is impressive. (+1)

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you ;)

Answer (score 6):

It is not bad to use the series
$$K(y)=\frac \pi 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-4 n}\frac{ ((2 n)!)^2}{(n!)^4}\,y^n$$
$$\int \frac {y^k}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}\,dy=-2 \sqrt{1-y} \,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-k;\frac{3}{2};1-y\right)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac {y^k}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}\,dy=\sqrt{\pi } \,\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (k+1)}$$ which make the integral to be
$$\sqrt{\pi } \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}{\Gamma
   (n+1)^3}$$

Now, considering
$$\sqrt{\pi } \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}{\Gamma
   (n+1)^3}x^n=4 K\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-x}\right)\right)^2$$ Using $x=1$
$$4 K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{\pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}$$ and several othe forms.

Comment: Could you tell me where did you found the equality $\int \frac {y^k}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}\,dy=-2 \sqrt{1-y} \,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-k;\frac{3}{2};1-y\right)$?

Answer (score 3):

Some natural generalizations are(here we use $K(k)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
\frac{\text{d}t}{\sqrt{1-k^2t^2} }$)
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^4-x^2+1}{\sqrt{1-x^2} }K(x)^5
\text{d}x=\frac{3\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^{12} }{1024\pi^3},\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(1-k^2)} }\text{d}k
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2}{2\sqrt{2}\pi^{1/2} }\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+k^2)K(k)^2}{\sqrt{k(1-k^2)} }\text{d}k
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^6}{16\sqrt{2}\pi^{3/2} }.
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 3):

Remarks: It is easy to obtain $I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n + 1/2)^3}{\Gamma(n + 1)^3}$ by the generailized binomial theorem.
In the deleted post, [Le Thu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iUEu.jpg) pointed out Dixon's theorem can be used to evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n + 1/2)^3}{\Gamma(n + 1)^3}$.

Using the generalized binomial theorem, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - z}}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{n} (-1)^n z^n
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\Gamma(n + 1/2)}{\Gamma(n + 1)\Gamma(1/2)} z^n.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 I &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}\sqrt{y(1-y)}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\Gamma(n + 1/2)}{\Gamma(n + 1)\Gamma(1/2)} (xy)^n\,\mathrm{d} x\,\mathrm{d} y\\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\Gamma(n + 1/2)}{\Gamma(n + 1)\Gamma(1/2)}
 \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,\mathrm{d} x
 \int_0^1 \frac{y^n}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}\,\mathrm{d} y\\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\Gamma(n + 1/2)}{\Gamma(n + 1)\Gamma(1/2)}\,
 \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(n + 1/2)}{\Gamma(n + 1)}\, \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(n + 1/2)}{\Gamma(n + 1)} \tag{1}\\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n + 1/2)^3}{\Gamma(n + 1)^3}\\
 &= \pi^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty
 \frac{(1/2)_n (1/2)_n (1/2)_n}{(1)_n (1)_n}\, \frac{1}{n!}\\[6pt]
 &= \pi^2 \cdot { {}_3 \operatorname F_2} \left({\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2; 1, 1; 1}\right)\\
 &= \frac{\pi^3}{\Gamma(3/4)^4}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Explanations:
(1): $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,\mathrm{d} x
= \int_0^1 x^{n - 1/2}(1 - x)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d} x = B(n + 1/2, 1/2) = \frac{\Gamma(n + 1/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(n + 1)}$$
where $B(x, y) = \int_0^1 t^{x - 1}(1 - t)^{y - 1}\, \mathrm{d} t$ is the beta function.
(2): [Dixon's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html)
$${ {}_3 \operatorname F_2} \left({a, b, c; a - b + 1,  a - c + 1; 1}\right)
= \frac{(a/2)!\, (a-b)!\, (a-c)!\, (a/2 - b - c)!\,}{a!\, (a/2 - b)! \, (a/2 - c)!\, (a - b - c)!}$$
for $a = 1/2, b = 1/2, c = 1/2$.